# Python utf-8 error

Tags: python, smtp

When I tried to send an email using python,I met this error,here is the code:

```
from_addr = '*@163.com'
password = '*'
to_addr = '*@qq.com'
smtp_server = 'smtp.163.com'

import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, 25) 
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.login(from_addr, password)
server.sendmail(from_addr, [to_addr], msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

then the output is it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\smtp.py", line 17, in <module>
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 260, i
    fqdn = socket.getfqdn()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 673, in
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: So what is your hostname? Does it contain non-ASCII characters perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `name.decode()` to solve problem with non-ASCII characters.